# Find domain and range of logarithmic functions

Tags: functions, logarithms

Find the domain and the range of this function
$$f(x)= \log\left(\frac{x + 4}{x-4}\right).$$

Comment: f\left( x\right) =\log \left( \dfrac {x+4}{x-4}\right) was not taken for this i had to write in that manner

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: the logarithm is only defined for positive arguments.

Comment: We know in a fraction the denominator can't be 0 so domain for this may be all real number except 4

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=\log(x+4)-\log(x-4)$. First summand: $x>-4$, second summand: $x>4$. Together: domain is $x>4$

Comment: x> -4 again x> 4 so, x>4

Comment: @Jency Yes, the intersection of $x>-4$ and $x>4$ is $x>4$

Comment: @Callculus Yes, thank you. I think I got it

Comment: But on the other hand the fraction is positive if $x<4$. So there is a contradiction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100482/discussion-between-jency-and-callculus).

Comment: What to do for the range ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{x+4}{x-4}>0$$

$$\Rightarrow (x+4>0\land x-4>0)\lor(x+4<0\land x-4<0)$$

$$\Rightarrow x<-4~\lor~x>4$$

$$\Rightarrow x\in(-\infty,-4)\cup(4,\infty)$$

For the range, first find the inverse that is

$$x=\log{\frac{y+4}{y-4}}$$

I suppose it's log with base $10$, then we have

$$10^x=\frac{y+4}{y-4}$$

$$10^xy-10^x(4)=y+4$$

$$y(10^x-1)=4(1+10^x)$$

$$y=\frac{4(1+10^x)}{10^x-1}$$

Then $f(x)$ isn't defined iff $10^x-1=0$, you can finishi the rest

Comment: what about range?

Comment: Hint: for the range you can first find the inverse of $\log \frac{x+4}{x-4}$, then check where it is undefined

Comment: Can you again please help me out with the range **please**

Comment: so $\dots$ do you know how to find the inverse of a function

Comment: I know how to determine the inverse but here is log ... I can't do antilog stuff !!

Comment: I am grateful to you,  boss

Comment: found the range. it's all real numbers not equal to 0.

Comment: $10^x-1\neq0\Rightarrow x\neq0\Rightarrow x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$

Comment: You forgot to take the case when numerator and denominator have at the same time negative value

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Thanks, it's a typo, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

*Hints.*

What do you know about the argument of the real logarithm?

For the range, set $f(x)=y$ and express $x$ in terms of $y.$ Then find the domain of $x=g(y).$